# JSON representation of Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have been provided an API endpoint and I am trying to test it out using Postman.
API has a Map<String,Object> which I am not sure how to represent in JSON format for Postman to be able to use.

Here is the Entity:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.abcd.xyz.option.Option;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Project {

    private String name;
    private String shortName;
    private String idName;

    private String language;
    private String buildTool;
    private String k8sid;
    private String dnsId;
    private String jenkinsUrl;

    private Map<String, Option> options;

}
```

..............

Option definition:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.abcd.xyz.bundling.ResourceFile;
import com.abcd.xyz.project.Project;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonTypeIdResolver;

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="option")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(OptionTypeIdResolver.class)
public interface Option {
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<ResourceFile> getFiles(Project project);
}
```

......................

OptionTypeIdResolver:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

// Handles the conversion of the "option" property of an Option class into JSON, or from
// JSON into the correct Option type.
public class OptionTypeIdResolver implements TypeIdResolver {
    private static final String OPTION_PACKAGE = Option.class.getPackage().getName();
    private JavaType baseType;

    @Override
    public void init(JavaType baseType) {
        this.baseType = baseType;
    }

    @Override
    public Id getMechanism() {
        return Id.CUSTOM;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object obj) {
        return idFromValueAndType(obj, obj.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromBaseType() {
        return idFromValueAndType(null, baseType.getRawClass());
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object obj, Class<?> clazz) {
        // Convert java class name to simple name, ie package.GradleOption -> gradle
        String simpleName = clazz.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + clazz.getSimpleName().substring(1).replaceAll("Option$","");
        if ( clazz.getName().startsWith(OPTION_PACKAGE) ) {
            return simpleName;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("class " + clazz + " is not in the package " + OPTION_PACKAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String type) {
        Class<?> clazz;
        // Convert simple name to java class name, ie gradle -> package.GradleOption
        String javaType = type.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1) + "Option";
        String clazzName = OPTION_PACKAGE + "." + javaType;
        try {
            clazz = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().findClass(clazzName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cannot find class '" + clazzName + "'");
        }
        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructSpecializedType(baseType, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescForKnownTypeIds() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

.................

Here is the POST body I am using:

```
{
  "buildTool": "gradle",
  "dnsId": "demo005",
  "idName": "demo005",
  "jenkinsUrl": "",
  "k8sid": "er5t-eks-oGWFNxUs",
  "language": "java",
  "name": "demo005",
  "shortName": "f",
  "titleName": "demo004",
  "options": [
      {"java": {
          "JavaOption": {
              "group": "com.example",
              "name": "f"
          }
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

..................

Error I get is :

```
o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.abcd.xyz.option.Option]: missing type id property 'option'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.abcd.xyz.option.Option]: missing type id property 'option'
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.abcd.xyz.project.Project["titleName"])]
```

What am I getting wrong in the formatting..?

Comment: How does OptionTypeIdResolver looks like?

Comment: @notescrew - added the definition

Answer (score 0):

Map<String,Option>

```
String = key
Option = Object
would be in this json format
{
  "String":{
       //option object definition here
  }
}
```

Your **"options"** field in this case is  taking a **List<Map<String,Option>>**  but not **Map<String,Option>** which is defined in your **[Project entity table]**

Comment: Thanks for responding. Issue actually was with the extra field 'titleName' I was sending in my POST. It was mistake on my part and actually the error message did say that too, however I kept thinking that it had something to do with Option.

Comment: For reference only, I added below code to my service layer to get a json view of the post object and that helped with the troubleshooting:
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`
`String projectString = mapper.writeValueAsString(project);`
`log.info(projectString);`